# Using @property on ARC

Tags: iphone, ios, properties, automatic-ref-counting

```
// .h
@property ( strong, nonatomic ) NSString *note;

// .m
@synthesize note = _note;

- ( id ) initWithNote: ( NSString * )note {

    self = [ super init ];
    if ( self ) {
        _note = note;   // _note is just a instance variable.
        self.note = note;   // 'self.note = note;' is using setter method.
        return self;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

`@property ( strong, nonatomic ) NSString *note;` affects setter and getter methods.
And by default, variables are __strong type on ARC.

What is the difference between `_note = note;` and `self.note = note;` then?
Instead of `strong`, `retain` on non-ARC make a difference in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are now effectively the same if you use `(nonatomic)`. However, they'll be different if you use `(atomic)` (the default setting) or, more likely, **define a custom setter**:

```
- (void)setNote:(NSString *)note {
    // Do something fancier than this
    _note = note;
}
self.note = note; // use the custom setter
```

versus

```
_note = note; // set the variable directly
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly...

If you're overriding a setter, you want to assign to `_propertyName` instead of `self.propertyName`, to avoid an infinite recursion:

```
- (void)setNote:(NSString *)note
{
    _note = note;
    // self.note = note; // <-- doing this instead would freeze, and possibly crash your app
}
```

Same thing if you're overriding the getter. In other situations you can use either of the two.

Comment: Actually `self.note = note` doesn't crash the app - it freezes it into an infinite loop of a setter calling itself.

Comment: You're right, it first becomes unresponsive from the recursive calls. It might also crash eventually after running out of stack memory space. Thanks for the correction, I'll update the answer.

Comment: @rokjarc, no, doing that inside a setter WILL crash your app due to a **stack overflow** (appropriately enough.) I've done it accidentally several times, and can say with certainty that it will crash. It takes less than a minute.

Comment: @DuncanC: you're talking about `self.note = note` inside a setter? True - eventually it will crash, you are correct.